# Mysql throwing exception on Regex

Tags: mysql, regex

This works:

```
mysql> SELECT '123456789' REGEXP '.{3}';#1

mysql> SELECT '123456789' REGEXP '.{10}';#2
```

but not this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM mymodel WHERE some_text_field REGEXP '.{100}';#3
```

throwing exception:
ERROR 1139 (42000): Got error 'invalid repetition count(s)' from regexp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you don't have a string which is 100 characters or more in this field.
You could try this instead, if you just want to check this condition:

```
SELECT * FROM mymodel WHERE LENGTH(some_text_field) = 100 ;
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. But i am just curious about the above queries. #1 gives 1, #2 gives 0 as results but #3 throws exception. If there are no matching rows, then answer should be 0, it shouldn't throw an exception.

Comment: I agree with that, it's kinda nasty :)