# Got error 'invalid repetition count(s)' from regexp

Tags: mysql, regex

I got the following error in mysql:

```
Got error 'invalid repetition count(s)' from regexp
```

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_text_field REGEXP"[A-Za-z0-9]{256}"
```

But when I replace `REGEXP"[A-Za-z0-9]{256}"` with `REGEXP"[A-Za-z0-9]{255}"` and below there is no error.

Is there any character limitation in REGEXP? Why does it not work when I use 256 or above but works when I replace it with 255 or below?

I looked into this, [Mysql throwing exception on Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319482/mysql-throwing-exception-on-regex), but it is not very informative on why the error is occurring.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As documented under [Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html):

> To be more precise, `a{n}` matches exactly `n` instances of `a`. `a{n,}` matches `n` or more instances of `a`. `a{m,n}` matches `m` through `n` instances of `a`, inclusive.
>
> `m` and `n` must be in the range from `0` to `RE_DUP_MAX` (default 255), inclusive. If both `m` and `n` are given, `m` must be less than or equal to `n`.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to regex and couldnot understand it completely. Could you help me?

Comment: @Avinash: Be more specific... what exactly do you not understand?

Comment: actually i didnt understand the a{n}, a{n,} & a{m,n} part.

Comment: could you provide me any link if possible.

Comment: @Avinash: The words "Regular Expressions" in my answer are a link to the relevant manual page.